# Update data into the database using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update data into the database, I am using jQuery but this function does not call the webmethod in order to update the data.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "WebForm6.aspx/Update_Record",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{FName: "' + FName + '", FStatus: "' + FStatus + '", UDate: "' + UDate + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert("Start!!! ");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("a");
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert("Sorry!!! ");
    }
});
return false;
```

Comment: please share controller code-WebForm6.aspx

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. The above code does generate a POST request that is sent to WebForm6.aspx/Update_Record (I even made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6k8y0j5k/ - run it with developer tools open and you can see the request is generated). Can you explain what you're expecting to happen that's not happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call for sure it will be hepfull to you.

```
        data: "FName="+FName+"&FStatus="+FStatus+"&UDate="+UDate,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: with changing your 'data' part. because data corresponding vaue should ne a json object.

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "WebForm6.aspx/Update_Record", 
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data: {'FName': FName, 'FStatus': FStatus, 'UDate': UDate}, 
    dataType: "json", 
    beforeSend: function () { 
        alert("Start!!! "); 
    }, 
    success: function (data) { 
       alert("a"); 
    }, 
    failure: function (msg) { 
        alert("Sorry!!! "); 
    }     
});
```

Comment: Never post naked solution , at-least try to explain the OP that what was the mistake is. Mention that why his/her code was not working, Where was the mistake , that is the proper way to answer here.

Comment: I supposed to write some description. anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On Webform6.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
public [type data] Update_Record.....
```

On Jquery

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "WebForm6.aspx/Update_Record",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({FName:FName,FStatus:FStatus,UDate:Udate}),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert("Start!!! ");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("a");
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert("Sorry!!! ");
    }
});
```